# Asked the user for a variable, need to figure out the rest

Tags: java

So in my code, I've prompted the user the input X for `StdDraw.circle(x,y,r)` that is supposed to calculate to the location of a stationary ball.

For the assignment I was given to formulas:
=0cos⁡(/180)

=−1/22+ 0sin⁡(/180)

To which I assumed that the variable t is related to total time, the variable of this equation:

= 20sin⁡(/180)

(I was also given the range equation which is: = 02sin⁡(2/180))

The variable "g" is 9.8.

I've already tried figuring out how to calculate y and r in terms of putting it into an `StdDraw.circle`, but am drawing up short.

Here's the code I've already typed out:

```
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BallGame extends JFrame{

public static void main (String[]args)
{
    Scanner cool= new Scanner(System.in);
    double angle, speed, g;
    g=9.8;
    Double x, y, r;
    double location,range, time;

range=Math.pow(speed,2)*Math.sin(2*angle*(Math.PI/180)/g);
    time= (2*speed*Math.sin(angle*Math.PI/180)/g);

    x= speed*Math.cos(angle*(Math.PI/180)*time);
    y=-1/2*g*Math.pow(time, 2)+speed*Math.sin(angle*(Math.PI/180)*time);
```

Comment: Check your equations, the ones for range and time differ from your formulas. x, y differ also. E.g. you got some parentheses set wrong.

Comment: I just checked them over and I don't see how the formulas in my code differ from the formulas I'm given? Then would that mean x and y (which are the locations for the stationary ball I'm supposed to draw) aren't equivalent to my range and total time?

How should I reset my parentheses caused I originally had them set multiple different ways but changed it to that to avoid the errors I kept getting.

Comment: `*time)` -> `)*time` and `/g)` -> `)/g`

Comment: Alright changed my x equation to:  x=(speed*Math.cos(angle*(Math.PI/180))*time); 
However, it's telling me now that "time" isn't initialized even though it is.

Comment: And also `t` is not `totaltime`. Think of `t` as delta t, that is the time that passed since the ball was thrown. For calculating the position you start with `t=0`, calculate x/y, and draw the ball. Then increase `t` and calculate/draw again, until total time is reached. I'd rename `time` to `totaltime`.

Comment: And where you calculate x and y you use `t`. Intitialize `t` to 0 and let it increase. Anyway you've been doing this for more than 5 hours, consider getting a break.

Comment: Would I use an if or loop statment to calculate for the increase of time to reach totaltime?  I would love to take a break, but when I start getting stressed out, I just need to finish what I'm working on in order to take a break.

Comment: Depends on your assignment whether to loop or not. I guess you are doing this on a UI thread, so looping would lock the UI for so long. I'd remember the current time when the ball is hit/thrown in say `timethrown`, and then delta t would be current time minus `timethrown`. Calculate x/y, draw the ball and return control to the UI. But do the loop first, it's easier to implement and fix the main things first. Refine later.

Comment: On a second thought, I think you can't do it in a loop. Because you would have to cause a periodic redraw in order to watch the progress... Without a look into the whole program I cannot be certain about my advice.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159119/discussion-between-huntress-and-yacc).